# Big data solution for frequent queries

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I need a big data storage solution for batch inserts of denormalized data which happen infrequently and queries on the inserted data which happen frequently.

I've gone through Cassandra and feel that its not that good for batch inserts, but an OK solution for querying. Also, it would be good if there was a mechanism to segregate data separately based on a data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Cassandra I will talk about it:

Can you insert in an unbatched way or is this impossed by the system? If you can insert unbatched, Cassandra will probably be able to handle it easily.

Batched inserts should also be handable by Cassandra nodes, but this won't distribute the load properly among all the nodes (NOTE: I'm talking about load balancing, not about data balance, which will be only depending on your partition key setup). If you are not very familiar with Cassandra you could tell us your data structure and your query types and we could suggest you how to use Cassandra's data model to fit it.

For the filtering part of the question, Cassandra has clustering keys and secondary indexes, that are basically like adding another column configuration to the clustering key so that you have both for querying.

Comment: But considering Cassandra, the question is how big or how small would the data have to be to ensure that unbatched inserts dont cause a load(balancing) issue.

Comment: Do you understand the coordinator node concept of Cassandra? The default load balancing policy of Cassandra is to split the incoming queries among all nodes, so that they can act as multiple paralel coordinator nodes.  Why are you batching the inserts? Is it to try to get better insert times or due to a traffic issue? Cassandra usually handles batched inserts slower than non-batched.